# Comparison of the expected values of A 2 5 and 2 3 4 in razz

Tags: ev, seven-card-stud, razz

Which of these two starting hands, A 2 5 and 2 3 4, has the best expected value in a heads-up razz game? A real mathematical argument would be welcome.

P.S. I am not asking for the EV of A 2 5 versus 2 3 4, but for the EV of A 2 5 against a random hand versus the EV of 2 3 4 against a random hand.